# JUnit Log messages to appear in Firebase Test Lab catlog?

Tags: android, firebase, junit4

I'm running JUnit4 tests using Flank/Firebase Test Lab against Android API28 devices, and none of my logging messages that I print from my test listener are being printed in the device's catlog.

I tried a few things:

**Attempt 1**

```
println("===TEST")
```

**Attempt 2**

```
import android.util.Log
Log.e("UnitTest", "===TEST MESSAGE")
```

**Attempt 3**

```
bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString(Instrumentation.REPORT_KEY_IDENTIFIER, MyTestListener::class.java.name)
bundle.putString(InstrumentationResultPrinter.REPORT_KEY_NAME_CLASS, description.className)
bundle.putString(InstrumentationResultPrinter.REPORT_KEY_NAME_TEST, description.methodName)
bundle.putString(Instrumentation.REPORT_KEY_STREAMRESULT, "=== TEST_FINISHED")
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().sendStatus(InstrumentationResultPrinter.REPORT_VALUE_RESULT_OK, bundle)
```

None of those approaches seemed to have included my logs in the `catlog` output... yet I can see that my test case ran and passed. Does anyone have any suggestions or know what I'm doing wrong?

When I run this locally with breakpoints, my code is definitely being hit, and messages are being printed to Stdout.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempt 2 should actually be the accepted answer:

```
import android.util.Log
Log.e("UnitTestClassName", "===TEST MESSAGE")
```

My specific issue was that the test execution path didn't go through these lines of code.